# virtual List<T> :“The function evaluation requires all threads to run”

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I am following the following tutorial to learn code fast.
[Code First to a New Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx)

I have done till the step 4: of the tutorial, the problem arises when i try to run my code. I encounter the following exceptions at the following code...

```
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }
    {"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}
```

with an inner exception

```
    {"Access is denied: 'CodeFastNewDatabase.Program+Blog'.":""}
```

when i try to check the db variable property a lot of them has the debug error saying “The function evaluation requires all threads to run”
The code is creating database in my local db also inserting the values.

This problem I can work around if I remove the virtual specifiers in class Blog and Post for the properties

```
    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
```

I am facing the same exception for my other projects as well. A lot of properties are showing “The function evaluation requires all threads to run”

I am working with Entity Framework 6.0

Edit:

Blog is a property of the DbContext Object, I have initialized in the main function of the program class. Then added the blog in the context followed by saving it. That created/updated the database and inserted my given value. the code is same as in the example link.

[Stack trace]
Here is the stack trace i captured.

```
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at CodeFastNewDatabase.Program.Main(String[] args) in f:\Dropbox\Projects\visual studio 2012\Projects\CodeFastNewDatabase\CodeFastNewDatabase\Program.cs:line 32
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Here is the stack trace for both the exceptions (outer and inner)

```
    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
    at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslateColumnMap(Translator translator, Type elementType, ColumnMap columnMap, MetadataWorkspace workspace, SpanIndex spanIndex, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Boolean valueLayer)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__a()
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__9()
    at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
    at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
    at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
    at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
    at CodeFastNewDatabase.Program.Main(String[] args) in f:\Dropbox\Projects\visual studio 2012\Projects\CodeFastNewDatabase\CodeFastNewDatabase\Program.cs:line 33
    at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Inner Exception StackTrace

```
    at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.TermCreateClass(RuntimeModule module, Int32 tk, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
    at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock()
    at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateType()
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.ProxyTypeBuilder.CreateType(ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.BuildType(ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder, ClrEntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.TryCreateProxyType(EntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.GetProxyType(ClrEntityType ospaceEntityType, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.Visit(EntityColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.EntityColumnMap.Accept[TResultType,TArgType](ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2 visitor, TArgType arg)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.ProcessCollectionColumnMap(CollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg, ColumnMap discriminatorColumnMap, Object discriminatorValue)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.ProcessCollectionColumnMap(CollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslatorVisitor.Visit(SimpleCollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.SimpleCollectionColumnMap.Accept[TResultType,TArgType](ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2 visitor, TArgType arg)
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslateColumnMap[T](ColumnMap columnMap, MetadataWorkspace workspace, SpanIndex spanIndex, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Boolean valueLayer)
```

Comment: How have you declared your `Blog` type? And could you post the full stack trace?

Comment: I have updated the question with the stack trace. And the code is fully illustrated in the example link i provided.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx

Comment: That's not a useful stack trace - it just shows you calling `Environment.StackTrace`, by the looks of it. The exception should have the full details in it already.

Comment: @JonSkeet Updated the post with outer and inner exceptions as you asked.
The outer exception System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException the inner exception is System.TypeLoadException

Comment: The code sample says to put `Blog` and `Post` *below* the `Program` declaration - it looks like you've put it *within* the declaration of `Program`. I don't know whether that's relevant, but it could well be.

Comment: Yes!!! that was it. I just took the code out of program class and it simply worked. Also the newly created database do not have any invalid character either :)

Thanks a bunch mate. This was very helpful.

Comment: Okay, I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message shows that you've used `Blog` and `Post` as classes nested within `Program`, whereas the instructions state:

> Below the Program class definition in Program.cs add the following two classes.

Personally I'd put them into separate files, but that's a different matter. Given that they're public classes, I'm still surprised that it's failing, but it sounds like that's the problem.

As for "The function evaluation requires all threads to run" - that's not actually an *error*, it's just showing a limitation of debugging when evaluating a property would need to use various threads.

Comment: Ok i got a new issue, not sure if i should create a new question for it or not, just want to run it by you guys first.
I tried to create an instance of DbContext with using(var db = new Context()), problem is it created the db once then later when i deleted the db to test it again it would not recreate the db. Any idea why i am having that?
Edit:
nvm i just called Database.CreateIfNotExists(); which solved my problem.
Thanks a bunch everyone for your efforts :)

Answer (score 1):

The code you linked to is written to target Entity Framework 5.  In Entity Framework 6, the virtual proxy objects use an implementation of `Lazy<T>` for lazy loading, and it has to be handled differently in order to be thread safe.  my recommendation is to use a `virtual ICollection<Post>` rather than `virtual List<Post>` with EF6, or drop backwards to EF5, which the tutorial you are referencing is designed against.

Comment: The problem persists in both EF5 and EF6. Also changing to ICollection do not fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that in my Repository, I was returning an `IQueryable<T>` but forgetting in my Service method to use the `ToList()` method on the returned result.